# Determination of symmetry, bilinearity and positive definitiness for a linear mapping

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, bilinear-form

My questions pertain to the following task:

"A Matrix $A \in M(n, \mathbb{R})$ defines a linear map:

$b_A : \mathbb{R}^{n} \times \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \qquad b_A(v,w) := v^{t}Aw$.

**For which of the following matrices $A \in M(2, \mathbb{R})$ is the map $b_{A_{i}}$ a scalar product? I.e the map has the properties that it is symmetrical, bilinear and positive definite?**

$A_1 =  \begin{smallmatrix} 4 & 2 \\ 1 & 4 \end{smallmatrix}, A_2 = , ... , A_6 = ... .$ (Here I have left out several matrices as I don't think they contribute to the question &  I intend to check them myself )."

I am not well versed in mathematical notation, & I am finding this question a bit unclear. I interpret the task to mean that I will have shown that $b_{A_{i}}$ is a 'scalar product' if i demonstrate the other 3 properties.

could someone please help me understand what i need to do for this task, so i can complete it for the remaining matrices $A_2 - A_6$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every required property of this map, to be a scalar product, corresponds to a certain similar one of the matrix $A$. For example, to show that $b_A$ is symmetric,
$$b_A(u,v)=u^tAv\\b_A(v,u)=v^tAu$$
should be equal as scalars. But
$$(v^tAu)^t=u^tA^tv.$$
Thus it is equivalent to $A=A^t$ i.e., $A$ be symmetric. So, to prove this property it is enough to check that $A$ is symmetric.
This map also inherits the linearity from matrix multiplication and distributive laws(you can easily check it).
For positivity, a symmetric matrix is positive definite if all of its eigenvalues are real and positive. To check it you may alternatively take a general vector $x$ and evaluate $c=x^tAx$. The matrix $A$ is positive definite whenever $c$ is positive.

Comment: he also mentions positivity, but leaves off the matrices. So it would be necessary to confirm positive definiteness as well. For 2 by 2, positive trace and determinant are enough

Comment: @WillJagy this is related to eigenvalues and I am not sure if he knows how to get them.

Comment: Agreed. However, he surely knows how to find the trace and determinant. I don't see how they could ask him anything about positivity without the 2 by 2 version of Sylvester's criterion, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_criterion

Comment: @WillJagy I made an easier method

Comment: @WillJagy I think your method may be easier in general dimensions.

Comment: Semsem, good. .

Comment: Hi @Semsem, thanks for the answer! I have recently learned about eigenvalues, but they are a new concept, and I didn't know they were related to this question. 

i) As I interpret your solution for the property of symmetry, is it correct to assume I can choose $u$ and $v$ to be vectors of my choosing?

ii) thanks for the tip about positivity. 

iii) for bilinearity, it is not clear for me how I would demonstrate this property. Do you have any suggestions?

thanks for the answer, it is already very helpful :)

Comment: Hi @WillJagy to the best of my knowledge Sylvester's criterion has not been mentioned in my course . Thanks for the tips!

Comment: @doom01 see the edits

Comment: hi @Semsem, thanks! I am happy to accept your answer- you have provided all the necessary information for me to complete the task. I'm still unclear about the concept of bilinearity- for example in your answer you mention that the matrix inherits linearity and I do not understand why linearity and bilinearity are being used interchangeably here. Also, it is mentioned that it is easy to check for the linearity property, however how i would do so is not intuitive for me (even if it is trivial). If you wish to clarify these points I would be grateful. Thanks, Oscar.